# Use string enum value in TypeScript interface as a computed property key

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I want to define a function returns different type of object based on the key I give. It's basically like the trick used here in `createElement` function

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3117

However, instead of string literal, I want to use string enum type instead. So I wrote something like this

```
class Dog {}
class Cat {}
class Bird {}

enum Kind {
  Dog = 'Dog',
  Cat = 'Cat',
  Bird = 'Bird'
}

interface KindMap {
  [Kind.Dog]: Dog
  [Kind.Cat]: Cat
  [Kind.Bird]: Bird
}

function getAnimal<K extends keyof KindMap> (key: K): KindMap[K] {
  switch (key) {
    case Kind.Dog:
      return new Dog()
    case Kind.Cat:
      return new Cat()
    case Kind.Bird:
      return new Bird()
  }
}
```

However, TypeScript seems doesn't like the way I put the `enum Kind`'s value inside interface as the computed property, it complains

```
A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.
```

Here comes the question, I already have the constants defined in the enum, I don't like to use string literal, is there a way I can make this works? Which means use the Kind enum's value as the computed property key in the `KindMap`.

Comment: [This is not supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16258) in current typescript version, looks like [it might be fixed in 2.7](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15473)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes a simple object with `keyof` is simpler than an enum in TypeScript:

```
class Dog { }
class Cat { }

const kindMap = {
    Dog,
    Cat
};

type KindMap = typeof kindMap;

function getAnimalClass<K extends keyof KindMap>(key: K): KindMap[K] {
    return kindMap[key];
}

// These types are inferred correctly
const DogClass = getAnimalClass('Dog'); 
const dog = new DogClass();

const CatClass = getAnimalClass('Cat');
const cat = new CatClass();
```

[Try it in TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Dog%20%7B%20%7D%0Aclass%20Cat%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aconst%20kindMap%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Dog%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Cat%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20KindMap%20%3D%20typeof%20kindMap%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getAnimalClass%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20KindMap%3E(key%3A%20K)%3A%20KindMap%5BK%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20kindMap%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20DogClass%20%3D%20getAnimalClass('Dog')%3B%20%0Aconst%20dog%20%3D%20new%20DogClass()%3B%0A%0Aconst%20CatClass%20%3D%20getAnimalClass('Cat')%3B%0Aconst%20cat%20%3D%20new%20CatClass()%3B%0A)

I tried to implement `getAnimal()` with mapped types but seemed to run into buggy inference. But looking up the class was easier.

Inlining the `getAnimalClass` lookup also works with type inference:

```
const dog = new kindMap['Dog']();
```

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/64740836/470749 first and then came here and appreciate your workaround for computed string enums.

Answer (score 1):

The original code almost works as-is in TypeScript 2.7.2, although it does have an error because values other than the 3 `Kind`s may be passed in.

You can say that it's possible to return `undefined`:

```
function getAnimal<K extends keyof KindMap>(key: K): undefined | KindMap[K] {
    switch (key) {
        case Kind.Dog:
            return new Dog()
        case Kind.Cat:
            return new Cat()
        case Kind.Bird:
            return new Bird()
        default:
            return undefined;
    }
}
```

I'd probably just use a map of the enum to the class constructor directly, as using it can easily infer the type:

```
const kindMap = {
    [Kind.Dog]: Dog,
    [Kind.Cat]: Cat,
    [Kind.Bird]: Bird,
}

const tweeter = new kindMap[Kind.Bird]();
```

If you want the function to instantiate the objects, you can also set up a parallel interface:

```
interface KindMap {
    [Kind.Dog]: Dog,
    [Kind.Cat]: Cat,
    [Kind.Bird]: Bird,
}

const getAnimal = <K extends Kind>(k: K): KindMap[K] => new kindMap[k]();

const meower = getAnimal(Kind.Cat);
```