# Use computed values on enums

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following situation:

```
enum T {
    A = "a"
};

enum U {
    [T.A] = "u"
}
```

I getting this error:

> Computed property names are not allowed in enums.

Is there a way to workaround it? Or maybe using a similar resource that would allow me to have similar behavior?

Comment: just to be clear, you want it to be `U.a` since that is the **value of** `T.A` and not `U.A` so it has the same key as `T`?

Comment: Yes, want it to be `U.a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option, while not necessarily ideal, is to use the explicit values from the `T` enum then have some compile time assertion using a dummy type definition:

```
enum T {
    A = "a"
};

enum U {
    // T.A
    a = "u"
}
/** this raises a compile error if not all values of enum T are valid keys of the enum U */
type _ensure_keyof_U_equals_T = typeof U[T];
```

Note you wouldn't actually use `_ensure_keyof_U_equals_T` anywhere else in the code, it would just exist to throw a type error if the enum didn't match the shape you want. ([example playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=45&pln=5&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAKlDeAoKKoEEoF4oCICGOANMqgEJa4BGRiAvgNyKKiRQCqCJKA9N7AHRouUPBRwAzAPaSaqKLwHkAFMAAeAY2AAHAC5QAlnv0BnEAHI9lYOrxhjwKJPFQbWw3gA2ASmHlsOSjwAJxw6RG4AKgioHQALEyggvBNgYxEXSQg3DwdgIKDJIINnEEk9Tw8oADdPMFTHZxZoOGCHGo99ABMoAGtgAE80pxjY3PBoDgjuRB1+rQcAfVBjMCDgBb7+pwW2JYBHME9jBbhsWfnhtgBtGABdeiA)) if T contains an element that doesn't exist in U it will give an error saying "typeof U doesn't have a property ___" so you have to make sure T contains that property for the code to compile. A little roundabout but does work.

This is to ensure that a value of type `T` can be used as a dynamic key into the `U` object that is created at runtime.  Note that one of the advantages of enums is that making them `const` which is not an option with this kind of architecture.

An alternative is to make `U` a object definition instead of a enum like this:

```
type U = (typeof U)[keyof typeof U]
const U = {
    [T.A]: "u"
} as const
```

This doesn't assert that every possible element of `T` is a valid key (although the `_ensure_keyof_U_equals_T` from above would still work exactly the same here) but does create an object / type combination that is nearly indistinguishable from the enum case, the only difference is that checks for string literals are a little less strict:

```
enum A {
    a = "b"
}
type B = (typeof B)[keyof typeof B];
const B = {
    element: "b"
} as const

function should_only_accept_enum_A(item: A){}
function should_only_accept_enum_B(item: B){}

should_only_accept_enum_A("b") // fails
should_only_accept_enum_B("b") // succeeds
```

But if you wanted to put [non string values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47933133/5827215) in that structure which feels like the kind of case you'd be doing this anyway it does allow that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how and where to use the _ensure_keyof_U_equals_T type?

Comment: if the elements of enum `T` are being used as the keys/names of enum `U` then having a type somewhere that just does `typeof U[T]` (where U and T are replaced with your actual unions) will throw a compile error if every member of `T` are not valid keys of the enum `U`

Comment: so you wouldn't actually use `_ensure_keyof_U_equals_T` anywhere you just leave it in your code so when maintainers change the unions incorrectly it throws a compile error at a location where you can explain what needs to happen in comments instead of obscure errors that take a while to track down to minor typos

Comment: Here is a related useful perspective about computed string enums: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47933133/470749